# 3ds Max renders textures differently than my game engine?

Tags: opengl, texture-mapping, 3dsmax

I've been trying to get my game engine to display textures, and I finally got it working. I used the UV coordinates from the 3ds model, however the textures are displaying differently.

This is the rendering in 3ds max:
[image]

and this is the opengl rendering in my game engine:
[image]

why are the textures layed out like that? I supplied texture coordinates from the 3ds file generated... does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Your UVs for this should be simple enough that if you post them we can probably tell you what is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out the problem... 3DS Max automatically scaled the texture to have an equal width an height, or else it will display weirdly like above...

Comment: I do find it surprising that 3DS Max scaled the texture.

Answer (score 1):

From looking at your picture I can only assume that UV coordinates have been assigned to different vertices that they are assigned to in 3DS Max.